# Canvas HTML - Smoothness between lineTo and Bezier curve

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas, bezier

Maybe this is more a math question but lets see:

I'm using HTML5 Canvas to draw a line chart.
The chart is basically Position X Time.
Each line represents a vehicle in a position (Y) in a given time (X).
I only have information about when a vehicle passed through determined points in the road. So if a vehicle stops between two points I don't have the information that it actually stoped, but when it passes through the next point I will be able to draw a line that will be almost horizontal, because the average speed, i.e. the line slope, will be really small.

In these scenarios we have defined that if a vehicle moved below 10Km/h I should consider that it made a stop and should draw a horizontal smooth line.

Basically I have to transform this:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
ctx.lineCap = 'round';

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 30);
ctx.lineTo(20, 50);
ctx.lineTo(220, 70);
ctx.lineTo(240, 110);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Into this:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
ctx.lineCap = 'round';

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 30);
ctx.lineTo(20, 50);

ctx.bezierCurveTo(
  50, 70,
  210, 50,
  220, 70
)

ctx.lineTo(240, 110);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

The problem is: **how do I chose good values for the bezier points?**
In the above example I have done it experimentally. I cannot find a way to programatically pick good point values so my lines don't look bad like these:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
ctx.lineCap = 'round';

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 30);
ctx.lineTo(20, 50);

ctx.bezierCurveTo(
  20, 70,
  180, 50,
  220, 70
)

ctx.lineTo(240, 110);
ctx.stroke();


ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 80);
ctx.lineTo(20, 100);

ctx.bezierCurveTo(
  20, 120,
  220, 100,
  220, 120
)

ctx.lineTo(280, 150);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="170" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

I'm looking for a computationally simple solution because this is redrawn everytime with a lot of lines, so I don't want this melting down my performance.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: I don't know if it is the most computationally simple solution for curve fitting but the fitCurve code from graphic gems is what I would use and there's a js implementation here: https://github.com/soswow/fit-curve/blob/master/src/fit-curve.js

Comment: genuine question: why would you lie about your data and make it look smooth, when you _literally don't know_ how smooth it should be? If all you have is snapshot data, then just show snapshot data. Don't make it look like you know more than you actually do, just show the data as is? Using connected lines at all is already questionable, this should be line-charts, since that's all you actually know. Why even insist on connecting the values with fake lines? That's not what your data lets you abstract/assume anyway.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans good question. The simple answer is: client request. Also I didn't understand what you meant by "using connect lines is questionable, this should be line-charts". What would be the difference?

Comment: Think points, not connect points, just big points, with a line going down to the x axis. That's the real data, and already makes for a great graph. Showing those points "connected" is already a white (or maybe much blacker than white) lie: you don't know what's happening between those points. You don't even know if things dropped to 0 and then went to 200 briefly. You have literally no way to truthfully fill in the in-betweens. I can appreciate a client going "we'd like a continuous graph", but part of being paid is going "... that's not science, guys, that's bs =(" first.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I do get your point man. But not always is best to see raw data. My client is not a specialized analyst and neither are the users. They want us to chew the data a bit and show them where the vehicle has a bigger chance to have stopped. Please don't go all judgemental about others work without having nearly any info about it.

Comment: I only have what you put in the post, and if you use SO, you're here for _all_ answers, including the ones that might not be great for you personally, but remember: you're not asking for you, you're asking for you, and everyone else who will find this question in the future, and they too need to first consider _why_ they are doing this, and whether that even makes sense. If you have clients that want you to do this then you should put that in your post, because it explains why you need this, and so removes the "you shouldn't want to do this" argument entirely.

Comment: So, with that said: can you expand on your code a bit so that it's a [mcve]? All that's missing really is just a hardcoded list of some data points, plus the function(s) that you'd use to turn those into a graph. Right now you're showing "bare" canvas calls, without looping over any kind of data, so it's very hard to give a good answer on how to make a sequence of points look good.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans oh come on now. My question is there and it is simple. I'm not questioning whether or not I should do it. I'm question how I can do it. All the code you need to answer my question (that is written in bold, btw) is there. If you could stop being picky about concerns that do not surround my true question it would be great. Anyway, I found a good solution and will be posting it soon as I get to my computer.

Comment: As the guy who wrote https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo: no, after reading through your question, I don't feel like the question is complete enough to nicely answer, and I'd like to see better code that more accurately reflects what you have, what you want to do, what you tried, why that wasn't what you wanted, and where you've gotten stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a good solution for my problem: Using line interpolation.

Having the following segments and imagine I want to smooth things between `B` and `C`, how can I choose some bezier points that would garantee a smooth curve instead of broken one?

[image: The scenario before smoothing]

First I interpolate the segment `AB` and find the point `B'`, which is the point the line `AB` would touch the Y coordinate for `C`. Then I use the same process to find `C'`:

[image: Interpolating points]

The points `B'` and `C'` make good points for the bezier in order to smooth things up to a horizontal line:

[image: bezier curve using B' and C']

This is also being computationally simple enough since finding the a line equation is rather simple.